# javascript Collection of an object accessible by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, collections, key

How can I make this happen in javascript??

```
People[key1][0].FirstName = "First1-k1";
People[key1][0].LastName = "Last1-k1";
People[key1][1].FirstName = "First2-k1";
People[key1][1].LastName = "Last2-k1";
People[key2][0].FirstName = "First1-k2";
People[key2][0].LastName = "Last1-k2";
People[key2][1].FirstName = "First2-k2";
People[key2][1].LastName = "Last2-k2";
```

Or maybe:

```
People[key2].Index[1].LastName = "Last2-k2";
```

Other clarification:

```
SomeObject["somekey"][0].FirstName = "whatever";
SomeObject["somekey"][1].FirstName = "whatever";
SomeObject["someotherkey"][0].FirstName = "whatever";
SomeObject["someotherkey"][1].FirstName = "whatever";
```

Thanks

Comment: `key1` is a variable (as `key2`, you name it ...). what is the value of it?

Comment: Do you mean  `var people = { "key1":{ "firstname:"First1-k1","LastName":"Last1-k1"}, "key2" : { ...... }}` then `people["key1"]` will get FirstName and LastName of key1 or `var families = { "fam1": [{ "firstname:"First1-k1","LastName":"Last1-k1"}, { "firstname:"First1-k2","LastName":"Last1-k2"}]}` then `people["fam1"][1]` will get FirstName and LastName of fam1 number 1

Comment: I need to put a collection of rows in People[key1] as well as People[key2], People [key3]...etc.  Maybe something like: People[thekey].FirstName[0], People[thekey].FistName[1]..etc

Comment: So there will be mulitple rows inside People[key1] and key2 and key3...etc. Me saying key1, key2 are just examples. The keys will actually be more like, "10", "12", "124"....they are ID numbers that will be converted to text.

Comment: Yes, @mplungjan.... like the last part of what you said... `people["fam1"][1]` will get FirstName and LastName of fam1 number 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using properties and indexes together, you are talking about Objects (which have properties) and Arrays (which have indexes).

Your initial syntax of: `People[key1]`, implies that `People` is either an array where `key1` is a variable holding a non-negative number or `People` is an Object where `key1` is a string the will serve as the name of a property of the object.

So, you could have:

```js
var People = ["John","Paul","Ringo","George"];
     var key1 = 3;  // Arrays use non-negative numbers as indexes
     console.log(People[key1]);  // "George"
```

Or, you could have:

```js
var People = {
        first:"John",
        last: "Lennon"
     }

     var key1 = "first";  // Objects use strings as property names
     console.log(People[key1]);  // "John"
```

Now, if we continue your code: `People[key1][0]`, you indicate that `key1` should be indexed with a number, so that means that `People[key1]` should return an Array. This would mean that `People` could be an array containing arrays or an Object with arrays as properties:

Array with nested arrays:

```js
     var People = [
       ["John","Paul","Ringo","George"],
       ["Moe","Larry","Curly","Shemp"]
     ];

     var key1 = 1;
     console.log(People[key1][0]);  // "Moe"
```

Object with arrays as property values:

```js
     var People = {
       Beatles: ["John","Paul","Ringo","George"],
       ThreeStooges: ["Moe","Larry","Curly","Shemp"]
     };

     var key1 = "Beatles";
     console.log(People[key1][0]);  // "John"
```

Finally, when we add your last pieces of syntax: `People[key1][0].FirstName`, we can see that `People[key1][0]` must be returning an Object because you are providing a property name to access, so the final structure could still use Array or Objects, but could look like these:

Array with nested arrays that hold objects that have properties:

```js
var People = [
       [
          { firstName: "John" },
          { firstName: "Paul"} ,
          { firstName: "Ringo"} ,
          { firstName: "George"}
       ],
       [
          { firstName:"Moe", lastName: "Stooge" },
          { firstName: "Larry", lastName: "Stooge" },
          { firstName: "Curly", lastName: "Stooge" },
          { firstName:"Shemp", lastName: "Stooge" }
       ]
     ];

     var key1 = 1;
     console.log(People[key1][0].firstName);  // "Moe"

     People[key1][0].firstName = "First-K2";
     console.log(People[key1][0].firstName);  // "First-K2"
```

Object with arrays as property values that store objects which have properties:

```js
var People = {
       Beatles: [
          { firstName: "John" },
          { firstName: "Paul"} ,
          { firstName: "Ringo"} ,
          { firstName: "George"}
       ],
       ThreeStooges: [
          { firstName:"Moe", lastName: "Stooge" },
          { firstName: "Larry", lastName: "Stooge" },
          { firstName: "Curly", lastName: "Stooge" },
          { firstName:"Shemp", lastName: "Stooge" }
       ]
     };

     var key1 = "Beatles";
     console.log(People[key1][0].firstName);  // "John"

     People[key1][0].firstName = "First-K2";
     console.log(People[key1][0].firstName);  // "First-K2"
```

Now, while your syntax could mean two different structures that both could work, you really need to spend some time and think about this from the inside out. You  appear to have objects with a `firstName` property as the deepest construct in your structure, but working outward from there, you seem to just be adding layers without any particular reason. Should the objects with `firstName` properties be enumerable? If so, it makes sense to have them in an array. But, why package them up any further? You need to decide.

Comment: Thank you very much @Scott Marcus! The last part of code you mentioned was exactly what I was looking for. It's just too hard to explain why I needed it that way. It's part of an AngularJS app I'm doing. Actually people names have nothing to do with my code, I was just using it as an example. The actual object will look more like: `OptionsLevel1[OptionSubtypeID][index].OptionID` and `OptionsLevel1[OptionSubtypeID][index].OptionName`. It would take forever to explain the whole thing....but anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Hawker You are welcome. Please don't forget to up vote and mark my post as the answer. Good luck!

Comment: For some reason, since I'm new to using stackoverflow, it won't let my 'up vote' show. And how do I mark it as answered? Plus, this question was marked On Hold...which bugs me. You obviously understood the question, so why did it get On Hold because a few others didn't understand?

Comment: Okay, so I didn't see the check mark...lol...I went ahead and marked your answer as the correct answer @Scott Marcus.